# How to use dynamic parameters in Mono retries?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm writing a web client for an API.
Every request should be accompanied with an access_token that may overdue.
What i want is to catch cases where request is failed due to overdue token, refresh it and retry the request. The issue is that I'm receiving the token as a Mono via the same webClient.

What I actually want is something like this:

```
private AtomicReference<Token> token
...
public Mono<ApiResponse> callApi() {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(token.get())
        .switchIfEmpty(
            Mono.defer(() -> auth()
                .doOnNext(token::set)))
        .flatMap(token -> performRequest(token))
        .doOnError(e -> {
             var newToken = auth().block() // I obviously can't block here 
             token.set(newToken);
         }) 
        .retry(5);
}

private Mono<Token> auth() {
     // api call here that returns token
}
```

So what's the correct reactive way to update token and then retry request with it?

===UPD===
I managed to handle it, however, it looks a bit wanky.
Probably you have a better solution?

```
private AtomicReference<TokenHolder> tokenHolder = new AtomicReference<>();
private AtomicBoolean lastQueryFailed = new AtomicBoolean();

public Mono<ApiResponse> getApiResponse() {
    return Mono.defer(this::getToken)
            .flatMap(this::requestApi)
            .doOnError((e) -> {
                log.error(e)
                lastQueryFailed.set(true);
            })
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(
                    3,
                    Duration.ofSeconds(2)
            ));
}

private Mono<Token> getToken() {
    if (tokenHolder.get() == null) {
        return auth()
                .doOnNext(tokenHolder::set);
    }
    if (!lastQueryFailed.get()) {
        return Mono.just(tokenHolder.get());
    }
    return auth()
            .doOnNext(tokenHolder::set);
}

private Mono<Token> auth() {
    // api call here that returns token
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Mono.onErrorResume`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Function-) seems to be the operator you are looking for: It allows you to switch to a different Mono (in your case one based on `auth()`) when an error occurs:

```java
public Mono<ApiResponse> getApiResponse() {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(token.get())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> auth()
                    .doOnNext(token::set)))
            .flatMap(this::requestApi)
            .onErrorResume(SecurityException.class, error -> auth()
                    .doOnNext(token::set)
                    .flatMap(this::requestApi))
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)));
}
```

Note that I assumed you get a SecurityException if the token is overdue. You can change it to a different class, or even a `Predicate<Throwable>` to catch the overdue token exception. It is recommended to catch this specific error instead of all errors, else it will also refresh the token on other errors, like when the service is unreachable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It defininetly contains some stuff I'm gonna think about. 
However, it seems I can't fully use it - if  onErrorResume fails again, the next try will be repeated with the same token that comes from token.get, when the expected behaviour is to refresh the token again.  I will update the post if I find the better solution

Comment: You can do this by pulling the retryWhen inside the onErrorResume. This way only the part in onErrorResume will be retried, including the refresh of the token.